trying to pass array in the view with error in the third
service one and two I can receive in the view but the third gives an error
Controller:
    $servicos1 = DB::select("select * from servicos WHERE categoria = 1 ORDER BY servico DESC");

    $servicos2 = DB::select("select * from servicos WHERE categoria = 2 ORDER BY servico DESC");

    $servicos3 = DB::select("select * from servicos WHERE categoria = 3 ORDER BY servico DESC");

    return view('adm.servico', ['servicos1' => $servicos1], ['servicos2' => $servicos2], ['servicos3' => $servicos3]);

View:
ErrorException
Undefined variable: servicos3 (View: C:\Users\Vivere\Documents\Code\congregacao\resources\views\adm\servico.blade.php)
When I change the order, the error shows problem in the last one
Controller:
    $servicos1 = DB::select("select * from servicos WHERE categoria = 1 ORDER BY servico DESC");

    $servicos2 = DB::select("select * from servicos WHERE categoria = 2 ORDER BY servico DESC");

    $servicos3 = DB::select("select * from servicos WHERE categoria = 3 ORDER BY servico DESC");

    return view('adm.servico', ['servicos1' => $servicos1], ['servicos3' => $servicos3], ['servicos2' => $servicos2]);

View:
ErrorException
Undefined variable: servicos2 (View: C:\Users\Vivere\Documents\Code\congregacao\resources\views\adm\servico.blade.php)
When I delete the third item and leave service 1 and service 2 everything works
View:
@foreach ($servicos1 as $item)

{!! $item->servico !!}                          

@endforeach

@foreach ($servicos2 as $item)

{!! $item->servico !!}                          

@endforeach





But I need to pass all three, help me!


As stated on the staging ground review, you pass a single array, not multiple arrays. view('view', [...])

In Laravel, the reason why the code doesn't work is because of the way the variables are being passed to the view. The view() method expects all the variables to be grouped into a single array, and you are sending multiple arrays separately. The correct way is to combine all the variables into a single array, as in the example below:
return view('adm.servico', [
    'servicos1' => $servicos1,
    'servicos2' => $servicos2,
    'servicos3' => $servicos3
]);

